# Accessing folders of a document library using Event Receiver of another List

Tags: development, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-server

as per my requirement I created a PDF using iTextsharp and i want upload it to a specific document set (dynamic) in a document library when an event receiver is triggered from a list.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: Do you want idea to implement it or are you facing any issues in your code ?

Comment: I just want to know how to get the URL of a document set which is present in a document library, not the relative url the absolute url so that i can add the byte file ex: SPFile f = mylibrary.Files.add("http://server/sitecol/doclib/docset/file.pdf",bytes,true) I just to get the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sample test code for your reference.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPWeb web = properties.Web)
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                    document.Open();


                    Paragraph para = new Paragraph(properties.ListItem["Title"].ToString());

                    document.Add(para);

                    string text = @"you are successfully created pdf file.";
                    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                    paragraph.SpacingBefore = 10;
                    paragraph.SpacingAfter = 10;
                    paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    paragraph.Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 12f, BaseColor.GREEN);
                    paragraph.Add(text);
                    document.Add(paragraph);

                    document.Close();
                    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    string libraryName = "doc";
                    SPList lib = web.Lists.TryGetList(libraryName);
                    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(lib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/testDocumentSet");

                    string dsturl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/test.pdf";
                    SPFile myfile = folder.Files.Add(dsturl, bytes, true);                    
                    lib.Update();                    
                    memoryStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Update:

Don't use encoded url in c# code.

I tested in my local SharePoint 2013 by creating a document set called [test, aaads], the code works.

```
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(lib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/test, aaads");
string fullurl= web.Url+folder.Url + "/test.pdf";
```

Debug Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The document set is having a comma and space Like Guha, Samrat and the url looks like '..../Guha%2C%20Samrat' is there any way to solve this ?? Or else I have to create a string and genrate the asked format. I also require to send an email so that the user gets direct access to the pdf I created.

Comment: Check my update.